# Is there any way to get full include directories for a CMake target including its dependent targets

Tags: cmake

Suppose in a CMakeLists.txt we have two targets

```
add_library(liba ...)
target_include_directory(liba PUBLIC /path/to/somewhere/a)
add_executable(exec ...)
target_include_directory(exec PUBLIC /path/to/somewhere/b)
target_link_directories(exec liba)
```

I'm know how to get `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `exec`. But only `/path/to/somewhere/b` is fetched, while actually source files of target `exec` would be compiled with additional search path `/path/to/somewhere/a` which is inherates from `liba`.

P.S. The reason I want to do this is I'm trying to integrate YCM with CMake, while compliation database generated by CMake is missing infomation for header files and writing a `ycm_extra_conf.py` is horrible when dependencies is complicated.

Comment: Well, the situation looks a bit unclear/weird to me. First of all, `/path/to/somewhere/a` is an absolute path? Should it be changed, when `liba` is `make install`ed?.

Comment: Also you may find useful this: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html